# Reinstalling Ubuntu and transfer data from OpenSuse

Tags: migration, reinstall

I want to use Ubuntu again,but at this moment my OS is OpenSuse. What would be the best way to install Ubuntu and transfer all data from OpenSuse to
my new installation ?

Comment: If you had your data (ie. `/home`) in a different partition; an installation of Ubuntu can be done (using 'something else') just be careful not to have the format checkbox ticked (for your /home). *Backup your data regardless before installing*.   I'd also note your programs/packages loaded (`rpm -qa`) in case later decided something was missing...

Comment: I decided not to migrate, and have Ubuntu 16.04 running in Virtualbox.This is for now the best solution. Although I miss this very nice forum . Thanks for the answer anyway. Have fun with Ubuntu you all !!